# Xubuntu 15.04 Live USB hangs in both live mode and when installing on Acer Aspire E5-573G-56RG laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, xubuntu, acer

**Xubuntu 15.04 Live USB hangs in both live mode and when installing on Acer Aspire E5-573G-56RG laptop**

I've been using this USB drive to install a couple flavors of Ubuntu on a couple systems without issue, except for when I try it on this laptop.  However, I was able to create a Windows 10 installation USB on it and it worked fine, so it's certainly possible to boot from this USB drive on this system.  I'd like to dual-boot with Windows 10 and Xubuntu.

**Booting in UEFI mode with Secure Boot on/off:**

I can get to grub and choose live mode or install, but immediately after picking one the LED on the USB drive stops flashing and the screen is just black (still on, just displaying black) and nothing happens, even if I leave it alone for a really long time.  Turning on `nomodeset` doesn't change anything.  Windows Fast Startup is disabled, and there's no Intel Smart Response Technology either (trying to troubleshoot using [these guidelines](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_UEFI_mode)).

**Booting in legacy mode:**

Starts out fine, I get the splash screen then the install starts, but gets stuck at `[    0.174664] pci 0000:00:14.0: can't find IRQ for PCI INT A; probably a buggy MP table` after a bunch of lines in the same format (stops at same line every time).

---

Now, I've worked around this before by taking the hard drive out of the laptop and plugging it into another system when I wanted to use the live USB, but I find this makes things a bit finicky and usually makes some sort of boot repair necessary, so I'd like to avoid that (also taking apart a laptop is a bit time consuming).

---

**EDIT**

So I popped the laptop open and put the SSD into my desktop (disconnected the other drives so the Windows 10 partition wouldn't mess with them like it did the last time I did this).  My live USB drive worked perfectly on the desktop and I was able to install Xubuntu 15.04 alongside the existing Windows 10 partition.  I tested grub by rebooting a few times and booting into each partition with no problems.

However, as soon as I put the drive back in the laptop I could only boot into Windows 10 (BIOS/UEFI only ever showed "Windows Boot Manager" in my boot options and grub never started).  I'm guessing grub configured itself for my desktop and its hardware/UEFI, and it won't work on my laptop without some changes.

Also, I noticed there seem to be a lot of threads out there regarding laptops with switchable graphics (like this one).  Any chance that's the root of my issue here?  I've never really worked with linux for an extended period of time before.

At this point I've mostly given up on installing linux on the laptop, but would like to see if anyone has been able to figure something like this out before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried again after giving up for a couple years and found the solution: BIOS version was bugged and wouldn't allow any Linux versions to boot.  Both upgrading and downgrading the BIOS fixed the problem.

Additionally, it was necessary to enter BIOS and in the Security tab enter "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing:" and find `grubx64.efi` (for me it was in `HDD0/EFI/ubuntu/`)

In the end it works in UEFI mode with Secure Boot enabled, dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.